# What is the probability of getting one pair and one trio when throwing five dice?

Tags: probability, dice

What is the probability of getting one pair and one trio when throwing five dice?

I tried to answer this question stating that the probability of getting $3$ equal numbers is $(\frac{1}{6})^3$ and the probability of getting $2$ equal numbers in the rest of the dice is $(\frac{1}{6})^2$, but you can have $6$ number options in the trio and $5$ number options in the pair, so I concluded that the probability is $\frac{6\times5}{6^5} \approx 0.3858\text{%}$.

I run a Monte Carlo Simulation in Python to check this answer, and I got a different answer, roughly $10$ times the probability just calculated. That is the origin of posting this question. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  While you're editing, note that *dice* is plural (*die* is singular)

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Can you work out the probability of rolling a three, then another three, then a four, then another four, then another four, Gonzalo?

Answer (score 1):

How I did it is that I split it into finding number of ways to get a trio and a pair, and number of permutations for $5$ dice rolls(I'm assuming we are dealing with $6$-sided dice here).

**Number of ways to get condition**

There are $6$ numbers we can chose for a pair($[1,1],[2,2]$, so on).

There are $\frac{5*4}{2}=10$ ways to chose the $2$ dice that are going to be the same.

There are $5$ choices(the other three have to be the same as well but not the same as the pair value) to choose the other values for the other $3$ dice.

So the number of ways to get one pair and one trio is $6*10*5$.

**Number of ways to roll $5$ dice**

There are $6^5$ ways to roll $5$ dice.

---

So, the probability is: $\frac{6*10*5}{6^5}=\frac{25}{648}\approx 3.858\text{%}$

(I'm not entirely sure of my answer so if you catch any errors please tell me)

Edit: Thanks Gerry Myerson for catching my error

Comment: OOOHHH thanks for the help. That was what my error was.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the help! I changed it